# Model-View-Controller in terms of an app

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, controller

I have coding experience, but I'm new to the world of **MVCs**.

I understand Models and Views, and I understand controllers conceptually, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how they work.

Would I have one controller for each possible screen state in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I have one controller for each possible screen state in the app?

If by "screen" you mean view, then a single controller can manage all the different states of the screen (i.e., view).

If by "screen state" you mean view, then the answer could be yes: one controller will manage one view.

At least, if you aim at a rather canonical MVC implementation.

If you look at the interface of any SDK controller class (e.g. `UITableViewController`, `UIViewController`, etc) you will see that a controller has got just one single reference to a view object.